# Path issues in windows when using storeAs - Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I am trying to upload a file to public/attachments/foo.jpg in Laravel using storeAs(), it is working correctly in ubuntu but not in windows.

```
if($isValidated){

    $newFileName = '';
    foreach($files as $upload){

        $fileName = preg_replace('/\s+/', '_', pathinfo($upload->getClientOriginalName())['filename']);

        $newFileName = $fileName.'_'.$upload->uploadTime.'.'.$upload->getClientOriginalExtension();

        $upload->storeAs('public/attachments', $newFileName);

    }

}
```

This block of code successfully uploads a file in `/public/attachments/foo.jpg`
But when I try this in windows platform I get a error saying `fopen ... failed to open stream : Invalid aruguments.`

I have attached the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZ0st.png) of the error .

NOTE :

1. I have added symlink like so `php artisan:storage link`
2. Using Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in the name of the file. It contains a colon `:`, which is not allowed on Windows.

Comment: Put if you see in the screenshot the starting path is in \ but the end of the path is in /  why is that?

Comment: / is there because you put it in there (`'public/attachments'`). \ is there because you're using Windows, which uses backslash instead of a normal slash. You can use `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, which will be either / or \ depending on the current OS.